# Are urls with ?page=something bad for SEO?

Tags: url, url-rewriting, seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is a URL with a query string better or worse for SEO then one without one?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15393/is-a-url-with-a-query-string-better-or-worse-for-seo-then-one-without-one)

I have a listing of members on my homepage. My dynamic urls are quite simple:

```
http://mysite.com/members?page=8
```

I just use the query parameter to go from page to page. Is this bad for SEO? Should I be doing something like this instead?:

```
http://mysite.com/members/page/8
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google explains the use and impact of URL parameters in this article: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.au/2008/09/dynamic-urls-vs-static-urls.html

The short answer is that with simple key/value query strings like yours, there's no issue.

Comment: In [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools) you can now state that a specific URL parameter is used for pagination: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/improved-handling-of-urls-with.html