# How important are SEO Friendly URLs

Tags: seo, url, links

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is a URL with a query string better or worse for SEO then one without one?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15393/is-a-url-with-a-query-string-better-or-worse-for-seo-then-one-without-one)

Currently, my URLs look something like `http://mydomain.ext/question/5` where `question` is the Controller and `5` is the ID of the object or article retrieved.

In theory I could spend some development time and some server resources to have URLs that would contain more information about the page loaded.

However, seeing how websites like Youtube or many others just keep simple URLs with just an ID, I am asking, does it matter? It is worth it??

Comment: Well I look at SEO friendly URL's like this. With all else being equal between your website and your competitors if your competitor has them they'll probably rank higher. That's my assumption. That with every single signal to Google being equal and you give them one more to base their ranking on it'll probably help to have a well written URL. Not keyword stuffed.

Comment: It doesn't look like a duplicate to me. The linked article asked about putting the keywords as a query string or as directories. This question on the other hand uses object IDs.

Comment: youtube would have a hell of a time with SEO Friendly URL's considering how many people re-post the same video. If you're building a site with zend framework or some other they tend to have URL re-writing libraries built into the framework. I can't think of ZF's off the top of my head but we use it.